# Django: Named URLs / Same Template, Different Named URL

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a webapp that lists all of my artists, albums and songs when the appropriate link is clicked.  I make extensive use of generic views (object_list/detail) and named urls but I am coming across an annoyance.  I have three templates that pretty much output the exact same html that look just like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="content">

<ul id="starts-with">
{% for starts_with in starts_with_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url song_list_x starts_with %}">{{ starts_with|upper }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul>
{% for song in songs_list %}
    <li>{{ song.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

My artist and album template look pretty much the same and I'd like to combine the three template's into one.  The fact that my variables start with `song` can easily be changed to the default `obj`.  It's my `<ul id="starts-with">` named url I don't know how to correct.  Obviously I want it to link to a specific album/artist/song using the named urls in my `urls.py` but I don't know how to make it context aware.  Any suggestions?

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('tlkmusic.apps.tlkmusic_base.views',
    # (r'^$', index),
    url(r'^artists/$', artist_list, name='artist_list'),
    url(r'^artists/(?P<starts_with>\w)/$', artist_list, name='artist_list_x'),
    url(r'^artist/(?P<artist_id>\d+)/$', artist_detail, name='artist_detail'),
    url(r'^albums/$', album_list, name='album_list'),
    url(r'^albums/(?P<starts_with>\w)/$', album_list, name='album_list_x'),
    url(r'^album/(?P<album_id>\w)/$', album_detail, name='album_detail'),
    url(r'^songs/$', song_list, name='song_list'),
    url(r'^songs/(?P<starts_with>\w)/$', song_list, name='song_list_x'),
    url(r'^song/(?P<song_id>\w)/$', song_detail, name='song_detail'),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define url patterns for a generic object_type instead of individually for artists, albums and songs:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('tlkmusic.apps.tlkmusic_base.views',
    # (r'^$', index),
    url(r'^(?P<object_type>\w+)/$', music_object_list, name='music_object_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<object_type>\w+)/(?P<starts_with>\w)/$', music_object_list, name='music_object_list_x'),
    url(r'^(?P<object_type>\w+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', music_object_detail, name='music_object_detail'),

)
```

Then in your template, your url tag becomes

```
{% url music_object_list_x object_type starts_with %} *
```

You may find you only need one view, `music_object_list`. If you find you need different functions for each object type, then call the individual functions in `music_object_list`.

```
def music_object_list(request, object_type, starts_with=None):
     if object_type == 'artists':
         return artist_list(request, starts_with=starts_with)
     elif object_type == 'albums':
         return album_list(request, starts_with=starts_with)
     ...
```

If you are using `django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list`, then remember to add `object_type` to the `extra_context` dictionary. This will add object_type to the template context, allowing the url tag to work.

```
extra_context = {'object_type': 'songs', ...}
```

---

* This is the new url tag syntax for Django 1.2. For older versions you would use a comma.

```
{% url music_object_list_x object_type,starts_with %}
```

See the docs ([Current](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url), [1.1](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)) for more information

Comment: I like where this is going!  I am trying to see how this is working as we speak.  If this goes according to plan I will be forever grateful.  The only thing I would change is using `object_list` as a function name seems to be conflicting with `from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list` but that's easily overcome.  I'll be back with my findings!

Comment: Good point about the name conflict. I've renamed the function to `music_object_list`.

Comment: I think I am having a hard time getting the `{% url music_object_list_x object_type,starts_with %}` to recognize the object_type in my template.  I am on Django 1.1.1

Comment: Haha, whoops.  I should of added my views but I fixed it by passing it through my `extra_context = {'starts_with_list': starts_with_list, 'object_type': 'songs'}`

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to mention adding `object_type` to `extra_context`, but I see you worked it out already!